# Kotlin layout width and height binding

Tags: android, binding, kotlin

I've googled and tried examples but I'm unable to perform binding a FrameLayout width and height. The other bindings work fine.

**Final Solution:**
Example project: https://github.com/jchristof/SimpleDatabindingExample

panel.xml:

```
<layout>
    <data class="PanelControlBinding">
        <variable
            name="panel"
            type="com.example.viewmodels.ContainerViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="@{panel.width}"
        android:layout_height="@{panel.height}"
        android:translationX="@{panel.left}"
        android:translationY="@{panel.top}"
        android:background="@{panel.background}"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

binding.kt kotlin file

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
fun setLayoutWidth(view: View, width: Int) {
    val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
    layoutParams.width = width
    view.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

I've tried a number of permutations on the width type (setting it to Float) as well as removing the android: namespace,  declaring the setLayoutWidth as a static companion object etc.

I continue to get the error:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type java.lang.Integer on android.widget.FrameLayout.
file:D:\Projects\strandXmlAppRunner\app\src\main\res\layout\panel.xml
loc:9:32 - 9:42
****\ data binding error ****
```

How do I need to change these declarations to enable binding on the layout width and height?

**Edit**

also tried adding an import to the binding adapter:

```
<data class="PanelControlBinding">
    <import type="com.example.services.BindingKt"/>
    <variable
        name="panel"
        type="com.example.viewmodels.ContainerViewModel"/>
</data>
```

same error

**Edit**

going back to my ContainerViewModel, I notice that if I change the return type of width from Int? to Int:

```
open class ContainerViewModel(val attributes: IValuesStore<String>) {
    val width:Int
        get() = placementArea?.width?.toInt() ?: 0
}
```

slightly different error:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type int on android.widget.FrameLayout.
file:D:\Projects\strandXmlAppRunner\app\src\main\res\layout\panel.xml
loc:11:32 - 11:42
****\ data binding error ****
```

type java.lang.Integer vs type int

**Edit**

per suggestion, modified to include default values:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="@{panel.width, default=wrap_content}"
    android:layout_height="@{panel.height, default=wrap_content}"
    android:translationX="@{panel.left}"
    android:translationY="@{panel.top}"
    android:background="@{panel.background}"
    >

</FrameLayout>
```

and

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
fun setLayoutWidth(view: View, width: Float) {
    val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
    layoutParams.width = width.toInt()
    view.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

makes no difference:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type int on android.widget.FrameLayout.
file:D:\Projects\strandXmlAppRunner\app\src\main\res\layout\panel.xml
loc:11:32 - 11:42
****\ data binding error ****
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make DataBinding work for `layout_width` and `layout_height`, you have to give a default width and height to the view. So what you can do is change xml to something like this:

```
<layout>
<data class="PanelControlBinding">
    <variable
        name="panel"
        type="com.example.viewmodels.ContainerViewModel"/>
</data>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@{panel.width, default=wrap_content}"
    android:layout_height="@{panel.height, default=wrap_content}"
    android:translationX="@{panel.left}"
    android:translationY="@{panel.top}"
    android:background="@{panel.background}"
    >
</FrameLayout>
```

And your BindingAdapter like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
fun setLayoutWidth(view: View, width: float) {
val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
layoutParams.width = width
view.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

Try this once, it should work. Let me know if it doesn't work.

**EDIT**

To make your project work, i have added these things to the `build.gradle(Module: app)`

**1** added `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to the top level plugins.

**2** added this to the `android` tag:

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

After these changes, clean and rebuild the project before running.

It will work hopefully.:)

Comment: i just checked it on my project and it is working perfectly, make sure you are doing all the necessary things required to do DataBinding and also, clean and rebuild the project before running it. Still not working, then let me know, i can dive more deep into it.

Comment: created this example project - it has the same errors as I posted above. https://github.com/jchristof/SimpleDatabindingExample

Comment: I fixed your problem, its working now. Will get back to you with fixes.:)

Comment: Updated the answer, please check and let me know the status.